# IIS npm start from webconfig

Tags: node.js, iis, web-config, npm-scripts, npm-start

I'm deploying my node express project with iis. pm2 don't restart after then server rebooting. can I npm start or pm2 start on webconfig file? what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

when you deploy your project use at the end

```
pm2 save
pm2 startup
```

based on [documentation](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/)

**pm2 Save**

> Once you started all the applications you want to manage, you have to save the list you wanna respawn at machine reboot

**Pm2 Startup**

> PM2 can generate startup scripts and configure them in order to keep your process list intact across expected or unexpected machine restarts

Comment: thank you for your help. However, when the server user log out, iis up but node project down. When user log in again, node project up. how to stay up when a user logs out?

Answer (score 0):

to run the node js application after the user logged out you could try to use **[Forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever)**  and or install forever-win using `npm -g install forever-win` and do then forever start app.js.